# Cinema4D: Exporting a scene as a 2D Vector image

Tags: cinema-4d

Since geometry is simply math, is there a way to export what a camera sees in C4D to a file format such as EPS or SVG.

What the camera sees is simply points, you lose the depth and imagine the scene as a flat drawing, where perspective is simply plotted points on a canvas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems that this question gets asked in various places, but is rarely answered. I managed to find the answer, and want to just do a quick write up on how to export as a 2D vector that you'll be able to open in Illustrator of Inkscape

### Open Cinema 4D scene

[image: Prepare your scene in cinema4d]

### File > Export > Illustrator

[image: File menu, head to the export item]

[image: Export as Illustrator .ai]

Turns out, it's **very** simple.

> Note: You must enable *Sketch an Toon* in your render settings to display the lines